# datatables with php and mysql large amount of data over 10000 records

Tags: php, mysql, flash, datatables

I'm using table-striped Datatables with my admin panel script and when try to display large amount of data from mySQL and PHP it take lots of time to load page.

Below is code using with datatables:

```
<script>

    'use strict'; var Site = window.Site;

    $(document).ready(function($) { Site.run(); });

    (function() 
    {
        $(document).ready(function() 
        {
            var defaults = $.components.getDefaults("dataTable");

            var options = $.extend(true, {}, defaults, 
            {
                "aoColumnDefs": 
                [{ 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [-1] }],

                "iDisplayLength": 10,

                "aLengthMenu": 
                [
                  [5, 10, 25, 50, -1],
                  [5, 10, 25, 50, "All"]
                ],

                "sDom": '<"dt-panelmenu clearfix"Tfr>t<"dt-panelfooter clearfix"ip>',
                "oTableTools": { "sSwfPath": "../assets/vendor/datatables-tabletools/swf/copy_csv_xls.swf" }
            });

            $('#exampleTableTools').dataTable(options);
        });
    })();

</script>
```

How to load all records and in same load page faster.

Comment: Tried using Ajax?

Comment: no I'm using php classes and functions I think it will be the same?

Comment: No it's not the same. Ajax is fast. Google php datatables Ajax. You'll get tons of answers

Comment: Loading all records from MySQL will always be slow, have you looked into paging the data? Or limiting it down to some subset or records?

Comment: Cant load all 10,000 at once or the browser will die, Must display fewer results at a time, maybe paginate, or lazy load, or ajax load 100 at a time as you scroll??? etc, limit query

Comment: Why is a browser plugin (Flash) involved? Is the Flash app `copy_csv_xls.swf` the one that shows 10 000 records?

Answer (score 1):

if you need a large amount of data than you have to set limits and pagination in php. 
The data table is set to limit after getting all of the data.
if you have larger data thank its necessary to set pagination in php.

Comment: It have automatic pagination on it but still load all data once and so page is so slow

Answer (score 0):

Like the others said. If you load 1000 entries at once, the page will be slow.
For that purpose you need to enable pagination:

```
'bPaginate': true
```

Also you should enable bProcessing with large amount of data:

```
'bProcessing':true
```

Use server side processing for faster speed, with an external .php file:

```
    'bServerSide':true
    'sAjaxSource': 'your_external_get_data.php'
```

Check out the documentation for more info: http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/features